# Need to stop the user click the exe for the second time, while it is already running

Tags: java, exe

I have developed a exe of my Java application, and run it from a thumb drive. It will take some time to execute. But my end user thinks it is not running and clicks for the second time. I need to stop this. I need to stop continuous click on the exe, while it is running. I used the shell script to check whether the exe is running or not.  And displays the message, that the exe is already running. And stops the further process. I need this to be happened while exe is running for the second time. I couldn't figure this out. Is there any way to disable the exe from click, while it is running. Or how can I use the check whether it is running or not.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class VBSUtils {

      private VBSUtils() {  }

      public static boolean isRunning(String process) {
        boolean found = false;
        try {
            File file = File.createTempFile("realhowto",".vbs");
            file.deleteOnExit();
            FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);

            String vbs = "Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject(\"WScript.Shell\")\n"
                       + "Set locator = CreateObject(\"WbemScripting.SWbemLocator\")\n"
                       + "Set service = locator.ConnectServer()\n"
                       + "Set processes = service.ExecQuery _\n"
                       + " (\"select * from Win32_Process where name='" + process +"'\")\n"
                       + "For Each process in processes\n"
                       + "wscript.echo process.Name \n"
                       + "Next\n"
                       + "Set WSHShell = Nothing\n";

            fw.write(vbs);
            fw.close();
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
            BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader
                  (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            line = input.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                if (line.equals(process)) {
                  found = true;
                }
            }
            input.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return found;
      }



}
```

And In my main class, I called VBUtils.

```
 boolean result = VBSUtils.isRunning("myexe.exe");
if(result)
{
     msgBox("myexe is running. Please wait");
}
else
{
 // my part of execution.
}
```

If I call like this, the exe got terminated. Both the first and second execution.

Comment: you can check this link for single instance limit: [http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_only_one_instance_is_running](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_only_one_instance_is_running)

Comment: Other approach is to use Launch4J where it can create a Java launcher EXE to become a single instance only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to present the user with some kind of visual feedback, so he knows that the application is running. (e.g. a console window with messages, a wait dialog, ...)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some sort of flag to indicate that your app is running. Many apps use a temp .pid file. When your app starts it checks for a .pid file, if there is one then it exits with an error message. If there is no .pid file then it creates one and runs as normal.

Comment: This is a common approach, though really I think he should do this *and* add a splash screen of some kind.

Comment: If you go the Pid file approach, make sure if the file exists, that you let the user know it appears to be already running, do you really want to start.  Or something along these lines to make sure your app did not exit without removing the pid file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all java has a provision for a very early splash screen:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html

Furthermore per **RMI** you can on startup connect to any possibly running instance and stop and transmit command line ("open files ..."). RMI allows you to play remote server.